# CSS Rotate inside rotated element not working

Tags: css, rotation

I'm trying to rotate an parent div with some child div's, and than rotate the spans inside the child div's back so that the text is still readable...

Here's an [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tU42g/)

The HTML:

```
<div id="bt_container">
    <div class="row_container">
        <div><span>col1.1</span>
        </div>
        <div><span>col1.2</span>
        </div>
        <div><span>col1.3</span>
        </div>
        <div><span>col1.4</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row_container">
        <div><span>col2.1</span>
        </div>
        <div><span>col2.2</span>
        </div>
        <div><span>col2.3</span>
        </div>
        <div><span>col2.4</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#bt_container {
    width: 1000px;
    height:600px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
.row_container {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.row_container div {
    width:70px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/wI9t0bj.png');
    background-size: cover;
}
.row_container div {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.row_container div span {
    color: white;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

But the span isn't rotating back ( it's not rotating on it's own ). So does anybody knows what i do wrong? / What do i have to do to make the text readable again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put a `display: block;` on your span in order to rotate it.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day! Been struggling with this for some time ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:inline-block` or `display:block` to the `span`. Or just use block elements instead of span.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That did indeed the trick. But emma was earlier, so she will get the "accepted answer" reward...

Answer (score 1):

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tU42g/3/)

edit display and padding (to show entire span text)

```
.row_container div span {
    color: white;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:20px;
}
```